# How can I pass the Jenkins BUILD_TIMESTAMP variable in the Build command to create reports?

Tags: jenkins, build, command, postman, newman

I have the below Build command in Jenkins-

```
C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm\newman run C:\\Users\\<username>\\Documents\\<Project_Name>\\API_TestCases_collection\\LandlordSales_B2L_L2Q.postman_collection.json -r htmlextra --reporter-htmlextra-export C:\Users\waniijag\Documents\<Project_Name>\NewmanReports\report.html
```

The issue is that report is getting overlapped for every new build. I want to make use of timestamp by appending it before the **{Timestamp}_report.html**

Also, I have enabled the environment variable in Jenkins as shown below:
[image]

How can I pass the timestamp in the above command?

Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Did you [read the docs](https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-timestamp/)? ${BUILD_TIMESTAMP} ?

Comment: Hi @IanW, Yes. But I did not get how should I use them. I tried passing "$Build_Timestamp" and $Build_Timestamp in my command. 
Example: 
```C:\Users\waniijag\Documents<Project_Name>\NewmanReports\$BUILD_TIMESTAMP_report.html
```
But, it did not work. Do I need to set that variable in the System environment also?

Comment: Install the plugin first https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-timestamp/ and then try as guided by @Michael

Comment: https://plugins.jenkins.io/build-timestamp/ is already installed.

Comment: Could you not just use something like `\report_$(date "+%d%m%Y_%H%M").html` or the windows equivalent to add a timestamp to the report?

Comment: Hey @DannyDainton, I have used that already. I want to know how can I use the inbuilt BUILD_TIMESTAMP variable of Jenkins. 
Thanks for the answer though :)

Comment: have you found an answer for this ? I am looking for the same

Answer (score 0):

The following snippet should print out the timestamp:

```
echo "${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}"
```

or included in your path:

```
echo "C:\Users\waniijag\Documents<Project_Name>\NewmanReports\${BUILD_TIMESTAMP}_report.html"
```

Important: You have to use `"` and not `'`.

See the [Groovy string interpolation](https://groovy-lang.org/syntax.html) docu for more.

Comment: When I'm using ${BUILD_TIMESTAMP} in the path, it is producing reports by appending ${BUILD_TIMESTAMP} in the report.html and not appending the BUILD_TIMESTAMP value.